# Radio buttons on angular formarray not toggling correctly

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a FormArray that loops with several test steps.  Beside each test step I am attempting to add a radio button group with PASS or FAIL.  When I select any radio option, it works.  However, when I click a 2nd row's PASS or FAIL radio options, the first is unselected.  How can I set up my radio buttons so each row can can be selected?

*Note: When PASS is selected, I want the value to be "1" (and FAIL should be 2)*

component.ts:

```
  test_run_steps: TestRunStep[];
  testRunForm: FormGroup;

  getControls() : AbstractControl[] {
    return this.getFormArray().controls;
  }

  getFormArray() : FormArray {
    return this.testRunForm.get('testRunFormArray') as FormArray
  }

  setTestRun() {
    this.http.get<TestRunStep[]>(`test_run/${this.selectedTestCase}`).subscribe(response => {
      this.test_run_steps = res
      this.initForm()
      this.initData()
      this.test_run_selected = true
    })
  }

  initForm() {
    this.testRunForm = new FormGroup({
      testRunFormArray: new FormArray([])
    })
  }


  initData() {
    this.test_run_steps.forEach(s => {
      this.getControls().push(new FormGroup({
        order: new FormControl(s.order),
        action: new FormControl(s.action),
        workflow: new FormControl(s.workflow),
        notes: new FormControl(s.notes),
        result: new FormControl(null)
      }))
    })
  }
```

component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="testRunForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreateTestRun()">
    <div formArrayName="testRunFormArray" style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Order</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Result</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let control of getControls(); let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">
                        {{control.value.order}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 40%;">
                        {{control.value.action}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 35%;">
                        {{control.value.notes}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="pass{{control.value.order}}" name="result" value="1" formControlName="result">
                            <label class="form-check-label">PASS</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="fail{{control.value.order}}" name="result" value="2" formControlName="result">
                            <label class="form-check-label">FAIL</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How do I bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 changes needed to be done to make your code work

**Change in Template code:**

No need of `name` attribute. Just `formControlName` is enough. If you use both, Angular will throw an error of saying their values should match

```
<td style="width: 20%;">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="pass{{control.value.order}}" value="1" formControlName="result">
    <label class="form-check-label">PASS</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="fail{{control.value.order}}" value="2" formControlName="result">
    <label class="form-check-label">FAIL</label>
  </div>
</td>
```

**Change in TS code:**

You should push the `FormGroup`s to `FormArray` itself not to the controls array

```
this.test_run_steps.forEach(s => {
  this.testRunFormArray.push(
    new FormGroup({
      order: new FormControl(s.order),
      action: new FormControl(s.action),
      workflow: new FormControl(s.workflow),
      notes: new FormControl(s.notes),
      result: new FormControl(s.result)
    })
  );
});
```

### Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w6n1jf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a unique name for each radio button group. You can give a unique thing like index **name = {{ i }}**

```
<td style="width: 20%;">
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="pass{{control.value.order}}" name="{{ i }}" value="1" formControlName="result">
        <label class="form-check-label">PASS</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="fail{{control.value.order}}" name="{{ i }}" value="2" formControlName="result">
        <label class="form-check-label">FAIL</label>
   </div>
</td>
```